# SQL Indexes to be used in WHERE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, query-optimization, where-clause

I have a table with 3 fields that I create a composite index. I need it to check if the record exists.

Here is my table

```
tblGamePlayLog
UserId (PK)
LogId (PK)
...
...
ProviderId
ResellerId
GameId
...
...

-- ProviderId, ResellerId and GameId is indexed (composite index)
```

And I have stored procedure like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [AS.uspProviderResellerGame_IsDeletable]
(
    @ProviderId INT = -1,    --Use -1 to ignore this field
    @ResellerId INT = -1,    --Use -1 to ignore this field
    @GameId INT = 1,         --Use -1 to ignore this field
    @IsDeletable BIT = 0 OUT
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET @IsDeletable = 1;
    
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ELSE IF (EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM [tblGamePlayLog] WHERE ((@ProviderId = -1) OR ([ProviderId] = @ProviderId)) AND ((@ResellerId = -1) OR ([ResellerId] = @ResellerId)) AND ((@GameId = -1) OR ([GameId] = @GameId)))) SET @IsDeletable = 0;
END;
```

This stored procedure allowed the calling function to pass -1 to ignore the check on a particular field. However, it caused a significant slowness on the query (1000x slower as the log consists of 1 million records).

If I remove -1 check, the speed improve significantly.

```
...
...
...
ELSE IF (EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM [tblGamePlayLog] WHERE ([ProviderId] = @ProviderId) AND ([ResellerId] = @ResellerId) AND ([GameId] = @GameId))) SET @IsDeletable = 0;
```

I suspect, but adding -1 check, the SQL doesn't use index check. My question is, how to allow -1 check in WHERE clause but preserve the index check.

Comment: `option(recompile)` may help here.

Comment: I agree with @GMB that the `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` query hint will be part of the solution. But you still need to consider that an index needs to have the leftmost column(s) of the predicate to be used efficiently. You'll need multiple indexes for efficient queries for your use case.

Comment: I tried to use `WITH RECOMPILE` in the stored procedure. It is still very slow...

Comment: I also used `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` as recommended by GMB, it improved the speed, but still very slow... :(

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend `option(recompile)`, so the database evaluates the literal parameters for every runs and computes a proper execution plan accordingly. The overhead of the recompilation should be less than the price you are paying now for a suboptimal plan.

```
IF(
    EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM [tblGamePlayLog] 
        WHERE 
                (@ProviderId = -1 OR [ProviderId] = @ProviderId) 
            AND (@ResellerId = -1 OR [ResellerId] = @ResellerId) 
            AND (@GameId     = -1 OR [GameId]     = @GameId)
    )
    OPTION (RECOMPILE)
)
```

Then, we need to look at the indexing part of the question. If you want the query to run efficiently in all situations, you need several indexes, basically all possible combinations of search parameters:

```
(providerid)
(resellerid)
(gameid)
(providerid, resellerid)
(providerid, gameid)
(gameid, resellerid)
(providerid, resellerid, gameid)
```

We can factorize a little:

```
(providerid, resellerid, gameid)
(providerid, gameid)
(gameid, resellerid)
(resellerid)
```

Comment: I got an error `incorrect syntax near 'OPTION'`. It worked outside the `EXIST()` statement. So, I put it into temp variable so I can use `OPTION(RECOMPILE)`, but it is still slow...

Comment: @Sam . . . Put the `OPTION` before the `)`.

Answer (score 0):

You might find that dynamic SQL -- with the right indexes -- is more consistent:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max) = '
SELECT @exists = MAX(flag)
FROM (SELECT TOP (1) 1 as flag
      FROM [tblGamePlayLog] 
      WHERE 1=1 @WHERE
     ) gpl
';

DECLARE @WHERE NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
SET @WHERE = @WHERE + 
           (CASE WHEN @ProviderId <> -1 THEN ' AND [ProviderId] = @ProviderId' ELSE '' END) +
           (CASE WHEN @ResellerId <> -1 THEN ' AND [ResellerId] = @ResellerId' ELSE '' END) +
           (CASE WHEN @ProviderId <> -1 THEN ' AND [GameId] = @GameId' ELSE '' END);

SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '@WHERE', @WHERE);

DECLARE @exists INT;

exec sp_executesql @sql,
                   N'@ProviderId int, @ResellerId int, @ProviderId int, @exists INT OUTPUT',
                   @exists=@exists OUTPUT;

IF (@exists = 1) BEGIN
     . . . 
END;
```

The construction of the SQL and the overhead for running it should be relatively small -- you need to run a query anyway.  This will guarantee the recompile.  You will also want to be sure that you have appropriate indexes on table, which requires a lot of combinations (GMB points this out in that answer).